# "Exchange Management Console" 2007 can't connect to Active directory on load : get-ExchangeServer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

Since a little time I can't use Exchange Management Console on an exchange 2007 server because of a message which tell me that get-ExchangeServer return that active directory of my server is available.

My config is :

Windows server 2008 sp2 wit roles :

- DNS
- IIS
- Active Directory
- RAS

and Exchange server 2007.

Here is a screenshot of the error message (I run windows server 2008 french edition sorry) :

[image]

in english :

```
The following error(s) were reported while loading topology information:

get-ExchangeServer
Failed
Error:
Active Directory server <theserver> is not available. Error message: A local error occurred.

A local error occurred.

get-UMServer
Failed
Error:
Active Directory server <theserver> is not available. Error message: A local error occurred.

A local error occurred.
```

Anyone know from where this problem is comming and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Is your Exchange server set to use your DC as its primary DNS server?

Comment: Hi Sam, where to see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answer to my problem but I resolved it by doing that :

> Go to the following location and
>   delete the Exchange Management Console
>   file.
>
> C:\users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC\Exchange
>   Management Console
>
> Close EMC and Reopen it.
>
> *NOTE:  Be aware, that You may loose
>   certain filtering preconfigurations
>   You made for that user.*

maybe it can help some.

now it's on microsoft support website :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019500